# <T> T[] toArray(T array[])

Tags: java

Can somebody explain in Java Collection Framework what the importance is of `<T>` in the signature

```
<T> T[] toArray(T array[]).
```

I know that `<T>` represents generic. But an elaborate explanation based on an example will be a great deal of help.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) then write your answer here. A tip would be to compare the explanation of the generic method versus the non-generic method.

Comment: In this link you find explanation with an example. it will be helpful [link]http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/linkedlist_array.htm

Answer (score 4):

This method allows you to create array of required type. The default toArray() returns Object[] which is cumbersome if you have list of Strings and you want a String[] from it.

For example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();        
list.add("A");

String[] listToArray;
listToArray = list.toArray(); // This won't compile as to Array gives Object[]

listToArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]); // This works when I want String[]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<T>` is the way Java says "in the method declaration that follows, `T` is a *generic parameter* rather than a *specific* class with the name `T`.

For example:

```
class T {
    public int x;
}

<T> T f(T x) { return x; }

T g(T x) { return new T(); }
```

The method `f` can be used with arguments of any type (such as `String`), whereas `g` can only be passed arguments of the class `T` defined above.  That is, one can call

```
f("dog")
```

but NOT `g("dog")` because a string is not a T.

[Runnable example at ideone showing how f and g are used.](http://ideone.com/1WHbi)